# Creating simple pixel (x,y coordinate) block letters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to find an existing piece of script that might help me write simple block letters out of individual pixels with x,y coordinates.

I was looking to automatically plot something like this as a minimum:
[Image](http://www.clivemaxfield.com/diycalculator/imgs/console-16.gif)

Although some scaleablity/quality functionality would be nice although not essential: [example](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2N3ku6-TyzM/UQi9NP7TXtI/AAAAAAAAARI/1Fl9Zya2KHk/s1600/iPhone_4_Pixel_comparison.jpg)

I am working with an interface that will only allow the most basic javascript implementation (i.e. basic loops, ifs and functions) without the benefit of using some of the larger all inclusive libraries around.

Comment: Do you have a question or you're just bragging?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<canvas>` element for drawing on and then define your block text as a 2D array, for example the letter "E" could be:

```
var E = [
    ["#","#","#","#","#","#","#"],
    ["#"," "," "," "," "," "," "],
    ["#"," "," "," "," "," "," "],
    ["#"," "," "," "," "," "," "],
    ["#","#","#"," "," "," "," "],
    ["#"," "," "," "," "," "," "],
    ["#"," "," "," "," "," "," "],
    ["#"," "," "," "," "," "," "],
    ["#","#","#","#","#","#","#"]
];
```

Where the value `"#"` is where the pixels are drawn. Then you can define a function for drawing `drawLetter(x, y, L)` where `x` and y` is where you would like to place the text on the canvas:

```
function drawLetter(x, y, L)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < L.length; i++)
        for(var j = 0; j < L[i].length; j++)
            if(L[i][j] == "#")
                ctx.fillRect( x+j, y+i, 1, 1 );
};
```

Finally you can call it by doing: `drawLetter(50, 50, E)`

[**2D Array Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuc6d0z7/)

---

If you rather use a variable that has an array of relative points instead you can do a similar concept, the variable isn't as *intuitive* than the last method though. So now assume we define a letter like:

```
var E = { {x:0, y:0}, {x:1, y:0}, ... };
```

Then you can simply iterate through the array of objects, the `drawLetter` function would look like:

```
function drawLetter(x, y, L)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < L.length; i++) 
        ctx.fillRect( x + L[i].x, y + L[i].y, 1, 1 );
}
```

[**Pure Point Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuc6d0z7/1/)